# Pass foreign key to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have two pages, one is a new player page which takes information from a user via text box and adds a new entry to the players db and creates a new auto-incremented primary key called `playerID`. This is working fine.

I then have another page called stat input where the user will enter statistics for an individual year for an existing player. I need a way for this second page to know the `playerID` of the player whose information is being added. I am not unsure of a good way to do this. Any ideas are appreciated.

Edit: I guess I wasn't very clear. The user may be going directly to the stat input page to add a new entry to an already existing player. The user will not know the playerID and likely only the name of the player.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: A few options - `GET` (to pass data between pages unsecurely), `POST` (to pass data between pages a bit more securely), or saving it in a `Cookie` (not very secure)

Comment: `<a href="secondpage.php?id=$your_new_id">click here</a>`

Comment: You can pass the ID on the URL's query string.  I can't imagine any introductory PHP/MySQL tutorial which wouldn't have demonstrated this...

Comment: I understand get and post. However it is unlikely that the user will be going directly from the new player page to the stat input. A player may already exist and the user just wants to add a new entry for that player in playerRegSeason. How can the user lookup a player to find the player id which is needed. I was thinkign about implementing a drop down box, but trying to come up with other solutions.

Comment: In this situation, I usually go with the dropdown box with the values as the keys.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this. Once you have the player ID, you can store it in a PHP session variable (if you are open to using server-side sessions). You could also pass it in a GET or POST parameter to the second page.

Edit:

As per the additional information you gave, I would go with a dropdown box with each player name. In the box, the "value" attribute of each  can be the primary key ID of the player.

Comment: there are over 3000 players. I have a three interdependent dropdown boxes that will widdle down selections to individual names. I think I should be able to pull the playerID from there though, correct?

Comment: @user2884621 Yeah, you should be able to pull the playerID. But instead of loading all 3000 player names into the dropdown at one time, it might be better to use AJAX for dynamic loading of the names as you narrow down the selections.